# J2ME LWUIT sound issue on Nokia N8 and C7

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, lwuit, nokia-n8

My app is a simple video player coded using LWUIT. The app works well on Nokia 5800, but i am unable to hear the audio in N8 and C7. Please help.

Comment: are you using volumeController in code ?

Comment: ya i am using it, however, it was a profile issue..Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you check the warning tone in the current profile? If its **OFF**, just **ON** the warning tone and play your video. AFAIK this is the problem. Check it.